# Binding data to a RadGridView on a child window in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, radgridview, childwindow

I can bind data to Telerik's `RadGridView` on xaml-pages, but I can't bind the data to a `RadGridView` on child window. I already have a list containing the data, but when I open the popup, the data of list needs to be bound to the grid.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be pass the RadGridView itemsource to Tag Property of ChildWindow, that way when you load your chilWindow you'll have access to the GridView elements.